# adding index.html and / at the end of url

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, url-rewriting

my project has two parts

1. using cakephp (added dynamic )
2. using html/css ( static - the old one )

p.s
static pages are under OldProj folder,dynamic pages are under myproject folder

And my problem is in static page url

eg. `www.myproject/OldProj/event/festival/index.html`
if user delected index.html,i just want to added index.html automatically

eg. `www.myproject/OldProj/event/festival/2014event.html`
if user delected /2014event.html from url ,i want to added / automatically
(`www.myproject/OldProj/event/festival/`)

my project of file/folder structure:

●myproject

```
  ●app
       ●controller
       ●view
       ●webroot
            ●OldProj
                 ●event
                    ●festival
                        ●index.html
                        ●2014event.html
```

i have tried in htacces files but....
if somebody know ,please help me

Comment: No offense, but I don't understand just one word. Someone visits `.../index.html` and it should add `index.html` automatically? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: sorry.when i check my site again,my question was wrong.my problem is a little bit similar to this one[stackoverflow.com/questions/12312499/… and so far que owner accept answer is not correct for me... @ndm

Comment: I think delected means deleted? Are you asking if /festival/index.html became /festival/ you want to add index.html but if /festival/2014event.html became /festival you want to add a single / ?

Comment: yes.delected should be deleted .sorry at that time i was in rush and didn't notice about that.:p